# How to add two format strings

Tags: python, selenium, syntax, formatting

I get invalid syntax at this line of code

```
sheets = ezsheets.Spreadsheet("id")
translation = sheets[1]
for x in range(2, 550):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"//a[contains(text(), {translation[A{x}}]"))
    print(translation[f'B{x}'])
```

Here translation contains the ezsheets object and A is column, while i want x to be a row

I also tried ".format" this way :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(, {}]".format(translation[f'A{x}']))
```

Comment: Do you want something like translation['A<x>'] eg translation['A2']?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yeap

Comment: Does your second option not work then?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Nope

Comment: What happened when you tried it? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: You appear to be missing a bracket at the end there in the second option

Comment: I added still doesnt work

Comment: @newbietoprog Please add your error traceback.

Comment: The string '//a[contains(text(), ]' is not a valid XPath expression. I tried to print the string this way to debug but it doesnt print anything : ```print("{}".format(translation[f'A{x}']))```

Answer (score 0):

In your template you forget to close `)` so that the evaluated expression has invalid syntax. Also you have expression within expression.

You have two options here:

1. `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),{})]'.format(translation[f'A{x}']))`
2. `browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//a[contains(text(),{translation[f"A{x}"]})]')`